# MySQL Is it possible to update rows that are grouped in a certain time frame altogether?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL to write a query for the following:

I want to update a value from one row to several other rows in the same table. There is no unique value between these rows at all. The only thing that can possibly link those rows are the date time of each row. Each "set" of rows are approximately between 5 to 8 minutes apart.

I know how to update rows from other rows in the same table, but a unique value is always present.

I write queries to retrieve the rows that are grouped in 8 minute intervals successfully but I still can't update.

If you look at the sample data: I want the batt_voltage values to be inserted in the blank values of the batt_voltage rows. But it must be inserted/updated where the times are grouped closely with the batt_voltage. The boot_msg 01 04 have the batt_voltage values. That value must be inserted into all the boot_msg 01 03 values where the time is max 8 minutes apart between the 01 04 and 01 03 boot_msg values.

Is this possible?

UPDATE:
I am including the query I was working on

`UPDATE node_startup_info AS N`
`INNER JOIN node_startup_info AS N1 ON N1.date_time = N.date_time`
`SET N.batt_voltage = N1.batt_voltage`
`WHERE (SELECT sec_to_time(time_to_sec(date_time)- time_to_sec(date_time)%(8*60)) AS intervals FROM node_startup_info GROUP BY intervals)`

Sample:

| boot_msg | date_time | batt_voltage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 03 | 2022-08-05 14:35:25 |  |
| 01 03 | 2022-08-05 14:35:07 |  |
| 01 03 | 2022-08-05 13:34:44 |  |
| 01 03 | 2022-08-05 13:34:25 |  |
| 01 04 | 2022-08-05 13:34:06 | 4058 |
| 01 03 | 2022-08-05 13:28:13 |  |
| 01 03 | 2022-08-05 13:06:14 |  |
| 01 04 | 2022-08-05 13:05:56 | 4095 |

I want the batt_voltage to update in the 01 03 rows from 01 04 rows where the date_time is approximately 5 minutes apart.

Comment: Is there a better, more SQL way of dealing with this, such as a GROUP BY at select time?

Comment: @Buffoonism I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: So you have a sparsely populated column, batt_voltage. When you do your SELECT, you can use GROUP BY, and then the aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, AVG etc.) to get you a value for the time range. https://www.guru99.com/aggregate-functions.html

Comment: @Buffoonism I did try it. I will update my question to show the query I tried

Comment: Please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so in the end I used this query (answer to my question):
`UPDATE node_startup_info AS t1 SET t1.batt_voltage = ( SELECT MAX( t2.batt_voltage ) FROM (SELECT * FROM node_startup_info AS N2) AS t2 WHERE t2.batt_voltage != '' AND t2.date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB( t1.date_time, INTERVAL 8 MINUTE ) AND DATE_ADD( t1.date_time, INTERVAL 8 MINUTE ) ) WHERE t1.batt_voltage = ''`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the extra info added above, I'd approach the problem in one of two ways (the optimal being based on whether the database needs to cope with lots of volume, at either the point when you insert the rows, or when you select them back). If there simply isn't much volume to be worried about, then just use the magic 8 ball to pick an approach. ;)

In an environment where the rows are selected frequently, then pre-generating the value at the point it is inserted will likely perform better. So if the row has a blank value, first select a value from the existing table, using the new row timestamp and an acceptable range. Something like (tweak as appropriate):

```
SELECT datetime, batt_voltage 
FROM node_startup_info 
WHERE batt_voltage IS NOT NULL 
AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( ?, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ) AND DATE_ADD( ?, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE );
```

For an environment where the selects are infrequent, then you can use the GROUP BY approach (tweak as appropriate):

```
SELECT FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( timestamp ) / ( 60 ) ) AS interval, datetime, batt_voltage
FROM node_startup_info 
WHERE batt_voltage IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY interval;
```

Comment: Thank you. The selects are infrequent and it will be large volumes of data. The update query I wrote and put in my question returns the error `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'N' for update in FROM clause`. Same thing happens with the second query approach that you suggested.

Comment: How about something like this? ```UPDATE node_startup_info AS t1 SET t1.batt_voltage = ( SELECT MAX( t2.batt_voltage ) FROM node_startup_info AS t2 WHERE t2.batt_voltage IS NOT NULL AND t2.datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( t1.datetime, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ) AND DATE_ADD( t1.datetime, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ) ) WHERE t1.batt_voltage IS NULL;```

Comment: Okay so I have been working on this and trying different methods and researched a lot. I feel I am close with this one: 
`UPDATE node_startup_info SET batt_voltage = (SELECT batt_voltage FROM (SELECT * FROM node_startup_info) AS N1 WHERE N1.batt_voltage != '' AND N1.date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB( N1.date_time, INTERVAL 8 MINUTE ) AND DATE_ADD( N1.date_time, INTERVAL 8 MINUTE )) WHERE batt_voltage = ''`

Except it gives this error: `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding ```LIMIT 1``` to the problem subquery.

Comment: Thank you, I posted my answer. Thank you for your help!